# Ideal transformer output voltage

Tags: transformer

I know that the output voltage and current of an ideal transformer depends on the number of wounding of the coils. It means that no matter how many resistors I put in a series in my secondary loop, the current would not change and it depends only on N (Number of turns in coil).

I have been thought that resistors define the current that flow through them and it is hard to look at the current independent of the load.

Could someone explain the physics behind `v1/v2=N1/N2`
So is it safe to assume that the current in secondary coil acts as an ideal current source because if I know the source current I can get the secondary loop current no matter what the load of the secondary circuit is

Comment: The current depends on the load. No load - no current. So your premise is false.

Comment: The current in the secondary loop depends on the current on first loop and N1:N2. I do not see any loads

Comment: how do you think the current will flow through an open circuit?

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. What I mean is that how come it does not depend on the value of the load. For example how would it differentiate between 10 ohm and 200 k ohms.

Comment: I am saying *it does depend*. The current in the secondary coil is v2/R. If you want to know the current in the primary one - apply the relation you've mentioned.

Comment: Let's say I have a current source and I know its value. I am going to connect it to a transformer with 1:a ratio. I can get my output current multiplying the ratio and the first known current (No matter what load the secondary loop has)

Comment: Connecting ideal current source to an open-ended ideal transformer is forming a non-physical circuit (something that can't work in reality).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35139/discussion-between-mary-e-and-eugene-sh).

Comment: ok I followed up in chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Could someone explain the physics behind v1/v2=N1/N2*

In a transformer **electric energy** is converted into **magnetic energy** and then back to **electric energy**.

The formula V1 / V2 = N1 / N2
applies to this process **without any losses**.

Losses can occur due to:

- Resistance of the transformer wires
- Saturation of the magnetic core of the transformer
- Inductance of the transformer (a transformer is also a coupled inductor)
- frequency of the AC signal fed to the transformer

So the formula V1 / V2 = N1 / N2  **does** apply **but** it only applies to an **ideal** transformer.

Also an **ideal** transformer does not lose any power nor will it add any. So that means:

P1 = P2 and also V1 * I1 = V2 * I2

If you would connect a current source to one side of the transformer then the relation will still hold **however** you must make sure that the current on the other side of the transformer **can flow** so you **must** apply a load or **short** it.

This is the opposite of connecting a voltage source at the primary side, you are expected to have a load at the secondary side or leave it open, **but you're not allowed to short the V2 side !**

Comment: So is it safe to assume that the current in secondary coil acts as an ideal current source because if I know the source current I can get the secondary loop current no matter what the load of the secondary circuit is?

Comment: If you have an **ideal** current source on the primary side and the transformer is also **ideal**, then **Yes** the secondary side will also behave as a current source, this means, no matter what the load is, the current is defined. It follows from the V1/V2 = N1/N2 formula and using a current source on the primary side.

Comment: In the book that I am reading the voltage and current ratios where derived in this way: First the voltage at the secondary loop was obtained by making the second loop an open circuit. (There is a voltage source at the primary side), then in order to get the current the author summed the voltage around the shorted coil of second circuit.

Comment: "you are expected to have a load at the secondary side or leave it open, but you're not allowed to short the V2 side !" this is what you said but I am looking at a shorted coil without any loads in the second circuit

Comment: book is nilsson riddle Electric circuits

Comment: What really confuses me that he obtained the value of second current for a transformer without any loads and then went on and calculated the impedance of a load using the same current

Comment: Looking at that book, chapter 13.6. What limits the current in this case is the impedance of the transformer: jwL1 So this is at a certain frequency (w =2pi*f) and the transformer has a certain inductance L. So when shorting the secondary side, the current on the primary side will be limited by Z=jwL1. The ratio N1/N2 still holds so then you can calculate the current on the secondary side.

Comment: In my answer I was ignoring the inductance of the transformer, assuming it to be zero. Then the current would be infinite when the secondary side is shorted.

Comment: So in this book the relation is derive for a special case when there is only an inductor in the secondary loop. How can he generalize it to the case where there are other circuit elements in series with the inductor.This is section 9.11 of the 10th edition.

Comment: The version I have is different, it has no section 9.11. But you just treat the transformer as any other circuit element. Determine its impedance Z(jw) and analyse the circuit as usual.